# refer equations across chapters

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to refer equations and figures from the previous chapters(showing in structure). I have to find the label from that chapter each time which is consuming more time. I want pop ups for all equations and figures in the whole document.(currently it is showing equation pop up for that chapter only)

Comment: This is clearly an editor problem. Untill you specify the editor you are using, we cannot help you. Also, do you have separate `.tex` files for each chapter?

Comment: I have installed texmaker 4.2 and I am having windows 7 OS. I have separate .tex files for each chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for seeing references only on a per-chapter basis is the following: you have not set a master document.

In order to do so, open the main `.tex` file in Texmaker (the one with all the input/includes of all your chapters). Then select `Options / Define Current Document as "Master Document"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was useful to me. It worked successfully.

Comment: No problem. It is customary that if an answer helps you solve the issue, you mark it as "Accepted answer".